# question about auto_ptr::reset

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

please can anybody explain [this code from C++ Reference site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/reset/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  auto_ptr<int> p;

  p.reset (new int);
  *p=5;
  cout << *p << endl;

  p.reset (new int);
  *p=10;
  cout << *p << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto_ptr` manages a pointer. `reset` will delete the pointer it has, and point to something else.

So you start with `auto_ptr p`, pointing to nothing. When you `reset` with `new int`, it deletes nothing and then points to a dynamically allocated `int`. You then assign 5 to that `int`.

Then you `reset` again, deleting that previously allocated `int` and then point to a newly allocated `int`. You then assign 10 to the new `int`.

When the function returns, `auto_ptr` goes out of scope and has its destructor called, which deletes the last allocated `int` and the program ends.

Comment: 'auto_ptr manages a pointer' - Is this really correct or does it manage the resource pointed to by the pointer?

Comment: @Chubsdad: I'll say it's correct in the same way that in `int *p = new int; delete p;`, the we commonly say the last expression "deletes `p`" when we really mean "it deletes the resource pointed to by `p`".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the example would be better as:

```
struct tester {
   int value;
   tester(int value) : value(value) 
   { std::cout << "tester(" << value << ")" << std::endl; }
   ~tester() { std::cout << "~tester(" << value << ")" << std::endl; }
};
int main() {
   std::auto_ptr<tester> p( new tester(1) ); // tester(1)
   std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
   p.reset( new tester(2) );                 // tester(2) followed by ~tester(1)
   std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
}                                         // ~tester(2)
```

The important line being where a new pointer is passed to the reset method. In the output you can see that the constructor of `tester` is called and then the pointer is passed to the `reset` method, the auto pointer takes care of the previously managed memory and deletes the object showing `~tester(1)` in the output. Similarly, at the end of the function, where the auto pointer goes out of scope, it takes care of the stored pointer printing `~test(2)`